# How to turn off Ionide Lint warnings

Tags: f#, lint, ionide

I have written a F# script in FSI using Ionide in VS Code. It's a great tool, but I am getting a warning from Ionide Lint suggesting a code improvement:

> 'Lint: `Seq.map f (Seq.map g x)` might be able to be refactored into `Seq.map (g >> f) x`.'

I have about 6 Seq.map functions all piped together with |> which I am happy with.

There is also a green wiggly line that is annoying me. I don't agree with the suggestion, and want the wiggly line to go away. How can I tell Ionide to stop making this suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have turned off Lint globally in the VS Code settings

```
"FSharp.linter": false,
```

I think Ionide uses FsharpLint: http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpLint/

This supports suppressing of lint messages like this:

```
[<SuppressMessage("NameConventions", "InterfaceNamesMustBeginWithI")>]
type Printable =
    abstract member Print : unit -> unit
```

Something like that might work for you as well. I just turned it off.

Answer (score 3):

This is the directive to disable this particular message in code:

```
open System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
[<SuppressMessage("Hints", "") >]
```

Place above the block that is producing this 'error'.